# How to handle a deliberately triggered breakpoint

Tags: c++

Let's say that I deliberately put something like; `*((int*)0xffffffff) = 1;` in my code. How can I prevent my application from crashing (triggering a breakpoint), when above line of code is being executed?

I tried to handle this situation with "catch-all-exceptions" statement; `catch(...) {/*Do something*/}`, just to see if this can solve my problem. As expected it didn't catch any exception, and my application has crashed.

Can this line (`*((int*)0xffffffff) = 1;`) crash my OS? 
What can I expect when this line of code is being executed? 
 
What alternative can I do to trigger a breakpoint on purpose?

---

### What am I trying to achieve?

I am working on heterogeneous system (CPU and GPU) in a heterogeneous environment ( classic C and C++ ).

As one might expect, I am trying to create a "unified" error-control system.

At one point in my application, where throwing an exception is a feature that is not supported (a classic C code), I want to trigger a breakpoint (just to report error). Then "catch" that "error" (in a C++ code block), handle it, and resume "normal" program execution.

**Creating enum type to store error codes, and then returning adequate error code from a function, is not an option.**

---

### System and problem spec:

**OS:** Windows 8.1 x64 
**IDE:** visual studio 2015 update 3. 
**breakpoint will be "thrown" from:** Classic C code. 
**breakpoint will be "catched" in:** C++ code.

Comment: `*((int*)0xffffffff) = 1;` is not exactly a deliberate breakpoint; it is a deliberate crash.  A deliberate breakpoint would be something like `asm { int 3; }`.

Comment: To `catch` an exception you must `throw` an exception. Executing random code with undefined behavior in the hope that somehow it will turn into an exception is not going to end well.

Comment: For Windows, you can "catch" OS exceptions using your own handler function and registering it with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx